# DELL-PRECISION-7530 with Intel AC9260 Wifi Not working on Ubuntu 16.04.4

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, dell

I new installed ubuntu 16.04.4 as dual boot in my new dell 7530 laptop.
It shows that my wifi network and it shows that it is connected. However, it not able to go into internet. The wireless adaptor is Intel AC9260.

The kernel of 16.04.4 is 4.13. In the intel website: it stated ac9260 required kernel 4.14+.

Anyway i can get my ubuntu 16.04.04 wifi working?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

Issue is solved, as Ubuntu have just update their kernel to version 4.15. 
AC9260 required Version 4.14 and above to work.